# Why does $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{1}^x_{(-y,y)}dy = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{1}^y_{(|x|,1)}dy $?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $\mathbb{1}$ be the indicator function, e.g

$$\mathbb{1}^x_{(0,1)} = \begin{cases} 1, \ x \in (0,1) \\ 0, \ \text{elsewhere}. \end{cases}$$

I've stumbled onto this integral, $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{1}^x_{(-y,y)}dy$. For some (obvious) reason, this equals $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbb{1}^y_{(|x|,1)}dy $. But I fail to see why. Any enlighten is much appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $x,y\in (0,1)$ (this come from the bounds of the integral). So,$$\boldsymbol 1_{(-y,y)}^x=\begin{cases}1&|x|\leq y\leq 1\\0&elsewhere\end{cases}=\boldsymbol 1_{(|x|,1)}^y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0<y<1\text{ and }x\in(-y,y)\iff$$
$$0<y<1\text{ and }|x|<y\iff$$
$$0<y<1\text{ and }y\in(|x|,1).$$